# Найти следующую картинку в галерее Jquery

Tags: jquery

Добры день, навоял [вот такой](http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/7tbAx/2/) скрипт для простенькой галереи, теперь не совсем пойму как получить src (в моём случае alt) для следующего изображения при клике на NEXT и PREV?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Ты должен *создать еще одну глобальную переменную*(!), которая будет отвечать за текущее изображение, например, currentImage.

В коллбэке orImg.on ты должен при щелчке присваивать переменной currentImage ссылку на тэг рисунка, по которому был совершен щелчок.

При этом у тебя всегда будет ссылка на текущее изображение. А для получения ссылки на следующее изображение ты можешь использовать функцию [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/). Ну, а как получать альт изображения у тебя в коде уже написано.

(!)*На самом деле, создавать глобальные переменные - не самая лучшая практика, но так как этот код тестовый, то тут можно писать хоть все в одну строчку :)*

Comment: Спасибо, я так пробовал делать но повидемому что-то упустил, а по поводу глобальных, я сделал все глобалльными потому что нет пока еще хорошего знания JS и неполучалось красиво, сперва  убрать кратинку, потом спрятать контенйер с каритнкой, далее убрать оверлей и очичтить стили контенйера с картинокой, та как вложенные друг вдруга коллбеки не видят нужных переменных.